# Display XPath of current element when editing XML document in Visual Studio

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xpath, visual-studio-2012

Is there an extension/add-in or feature of Visual Studio that will display the XPath expression for the current element when editing an XML document?

I use VS2012 and VS2010

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've just found this a tool called http://reasoncodeexample.com/2013/04/29/xpath-information-in-visual-studio/

Direct link: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c06c7b10-41c3-4aa9-8707-570eb9d879e6

It does exactly that. However, I don't know if it works in 2010, it says it should work in 2012 .

Comment: As of now, this extension supports VS 2012, 2013 and 2015

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you seek:

[Liquid Technologies XPath Tools](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/XPath-Viewer.aspx)

Under "Features"

"Build XPath expression directly from the element"
"Microsoft Visual Studio Integration"

---Update:
Those seem to be two separate features, unfortunately.  In the Liquid XML Studio desktop app, you can select XML and choose "Build XPath Expression".  But, I cannot figure out how perform that task in the Visual Studio add-in.

Answer (score 1):

The extension you want is "XPath Information". In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Online -> Search for "XPath Information" and install it.

Example:
[image]

Comment: I think that's the same extension that @Zyberzero already suggested